# Convert view to bitmap give black result when it not attach to parent view

Tags: android, file, view, bitmap, export

Hello I'm new on stack overflow. I got blank bitmap result when I convert view to bitmap when it not attach to parent view. Below is my code :

This is my failed experiment :

```
relativeLayoutContainer = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative_layout_container);
    relativeLayoutToFile = new RelativeLayout(this);
    relativeLayoutToFile.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE );
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(2000, 2000);
    relativeLayoutToFile.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    View view = new View(this);
    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(200,200);
    view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams1);
    relativeLayoutToFile.addView(view);
```

And below is how I convert the view to bitmap :

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(relativeLayoutToFile.getMeasuredWidth(), relativeLayoutToFile.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
relativeLayoutToFile.draw(canvas);
```

Note : I already log width and height value, and the value is not 0

Thanks All

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View view) {
    view.measure(MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight(),
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    view.layout(0, 0, view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight());
    view.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
}
```

Pass your view there and get a bitmap

Comment: I have tried add view.layout(..) but it didn't work :(

Comment: Convert RelativeLayout to View

Comment: the result is same, just note that this will work when view (relativeLayout) attached on screen, but I don't want to attached it because if I attached it to parent view or screen, when I set width and height more than screen size it will force to fit screen size.

Answer (score 0):

```
public Bitmap Image(final View view) {
    Bitmap  bmp=getBitmapOFRootView(view);
    final Bitmap copyBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp,0, 0,view.getWidth(), view.getHeight());
     return copyBitmap;
}



public Bitmap getBitmapOFRootView(View v) {
        View rootview = v.getRootView();
        rootview.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap bitmap1 = rootview.getDrawingCache();
        return bitmap1;
    }
```

use this and pass you view to it